# Möbius function of a linearly (totally) ordered set

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, mobius-function

Let $I_n$ be a totally ordered set ${1<2<...<n}$. We need to calculate $\mu(m,n)$.

We shall use the recursive definition of $\mu$.
We have the following:
$$\mu(m,m) = 1$$
$$\mu(m,m+1) = -\sum_{m < y< m+1} \mu(m,y) = 0$$

Let by strong induction $\mu(m,m+1), \mu(m,m+2),..., \mu(m,m+k-1) =0$ Then:

$$\mu(m,m+k) = -\sum_{m < y< m+1} \mu(m,y) = -(\mu(m,m+1)+....\mu(m,m+k-1)=0$$

Thus we have:
$\mu(m,n) = 1$ if $m=n$. Else, $\mu(m,n) = 0$ if $m \neq n$

---

Here are my doubts:

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Is the inequalities in the sum correct?
3. Whats the right recursive relation for $\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<y$ the correct recurrence is

$$\mu(x,y)=-\sum_{x\le z<y}\mu(x,z)\,,$$

so you should have

$$\mu(m,m+1)=-\sum_{m\color{red}{\le}y<m+1}\mu(m,y)=-\mu(m,m)=-1\,.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\mu(m,m+2)&=-\sum_{m\le y<m+2}\mu(m,y)\\
&=-\mu(m,m)-\mu(m,m+1)\\
&=-1-(-1)\\
&=0\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now try an induction on $k$ to get $\mu(m,m+k)$ for $k\ge 2$.